# Get caller in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

How to get SignalR caller outside of hub class? First I implement context but can't retrive caller or connection id.

```
    private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
    }
```

ConnectionId property also can't access from HomeController.

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

And finally have an error trying access hub on the client
`var id = $.connection.hub.id;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Think about it: how could you possibly retrieve the caller from outside the hub in every circumstance? You might be in a call which hasn't been done through SignalR, therefore you cannot have a caller in such a case. `IHubContext` has to cover all cases, therefore it can't offer such an option.

Comment: For exemple I have an event on client like button click, then retrive connectionid like "c96b4106-9986-4786-a755-eedccd204c79" and send to HomeController. Why can't I aswer to particular connection in this case? Only to All or Group is possible and no variants?

Comment: That is different, that's not the Caller, but a specific connection. In this case you can use the Client member of Clients - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.ihubconnectioncontext.client(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Could you advice any source how to build simple progress bar?

Comment: No, but just user a jQuery progress bar and update its value from a SignalR client-side event, it should be fairly simple. http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Client side wiget is not a problem. I like this one http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I mean how to start counter outside of Hub class and broadcast a status in real-time only to "caller", not to all.